# How can I require input fields to have more than three characters?

Tags: javascript, forms

```
function validate(){
    let name = document.getElementById('first_name');
    if(name.value.length > 3){
        return true;
    }else
    {
        document.getElementById('name').innerText = 'First name should be more the Three Characters';
        name.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Above is the function, what may be wrong here?

here is the html

```
<form method="POST" onSubmit = "return Validate();">
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label>First name</label>
            <span id="name" class="info"></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" name="first_name" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label>Last name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-8">
            <label>Town name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="town_name" required>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" name="add">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I want to only make validation for the first name field, where a user should enter a name that has at least three characters using javascript!

Comment: Show us your markup as well.

Comment: i have added the mark up, please check it

Comment: Where are you calling your function? You need to write an [event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events).

Comment: `Validate()` !== `validate()`; JavaScript is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use HTML5 validation?

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" name="first_name" required pattern="[A-Za-z]{3,}">
```

The `pattern="[A-Za-z]{3,}"` is the important part - it's a regular expression that enforces the content of the box to be alphabetical characters with a minimum of 3 (and no maximum)